# React redux- lost state after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i'm working on a project where there's an authentication, and i'm storing user infos after registration using redux store. I've made a test on the header component(if there's a user then logout will be displayed, else an avatar will be displayed), the probleme that i could dispatch new user information to the store, but when i refresh the page, i lose store state(goes back to null)
My userSlice code:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { fetchCount } from './counterAPI';

const initialState = {
  value: 0,
  status: 'idle',
};

export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'counter/fetchCount',
  async (amount) => {
    const response = await fetchCount(amount);
    // The value we return becomes the `fulfilled` action payload
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user:null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout} = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;


export default userSlice.reducer;
```

My register component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../../styles/auth/register.css'
import Footer from '../Footer.jsx';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {selectUser, login, logout} from '../../features/userSlice'
const Register = () => {
    const user = useSelector(selectUser)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const history = useHistory()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [registerInputs, setRegsiterInputs] = useState({
        email:'',
        full_name:'',
        user_name:'',
        password: '',
    })
    const changeInput = (e) => {
        e.persist()
        setRegsiterInputs({...registerInputs, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
    }

    const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setLoading(true)
        const data = {
            full_name : registerInputs.full_name,
            user_name : registerInputs.user_name,
            password : registerInputs.password,
            email : registerInputs.email
        }

        axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            axios.post('api/register', data).then((res) => {
                if(res.data.success) {
                    dispatch(login({
                        email: res.data.data.email,
                        full_name: res.data.data.full_name,
                        user_name : res.data.data.user_name
                    }))
                    console.log(user)
                    history.push('/')
                }else {
                    alert('Please fill all the information needed')
                }
            })
        });
        setLoading(false)
        
    }
    return  <div className="register">
    <div className="register__container">
            <div className="register__form">
                <div className="register__form__header">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <div className="header_p">
                        <p>Inscrivez-vous pour voir les photos et vidéos de vos amis.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button>Se connecter Avec facebook</button>
                </div>

                <div className="register__form__body">
                    <form>
                        <input name="email" value={registerInputs.email} onChange={changeInput} type ="text" placeholder="Email"/>
                        <input name="full_name" value={registerInputs.full_name} onChange={changeInput} type ="text" placeholder="Nom Complet"/>
                        <input name="user_name" value={registerInputs.user_name} onChange={changeInput} type ="text" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur"/>
                        <input name="password" value={registerInputs.password} onChange={changeInput} type ="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"/>
                        <button disabled={loading} onClick={register} type="submit">Insctiption</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div className="register__form__footer">
                    <p>
                    En vous inscrivant, vous acceptez nos Conditions générales, notre Politique d’utilisation des données et notre Politique d’utilisation des cookies. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="register__ignore">
                <p>Vous avez un compte? <Link to ="/login">Connectez-vous</Link></p>
            </div>

    </div>
    <Footer />
    </div>
}

export default Register;
```

Any changes i should do to prevent losing redux state after reloading page?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Persist your store to longterm storage, i.e. `localStorage`. Read from `localStorage` when initializing your store.

Answer (score 0):

Your Redux store is stored in memory therefore it will be purged on every refresh/navigation. To prevent that you must dump your store to some non-volatile storage like `LocalStorage`. Then you can load it up and pass to your store.

There is `redux-persist` library which automagically does it for you.